# JWT token authentication using next.js 14

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt

I am working on a web application whose back-end uses Django and front-end uses Next.js 14. I want to obtain a JWT token from the API and save it to an HTTP-only cookie. To implement logic for protected paths, I need to send this token to the back-end using the API and check if it’s valid. How can I save this token in an HTTP-only cookie and how can I access this token?

Another question I have is about displaying user-specific content on their profile page. Is there any parameter that I need to obtain from the login and signup API when a user is authorized, in order to display their specific content? For example, a userID or something similar

this is the api that i implemented in app/api path for signup:

```
// app/api/signup/route.js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
      try {
        // Send credentials to your backend
        const { email, password,confirm_password,phone_number } = req.body;
        const backendResponse = await fetch('api/accounts/signup/', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ email, password ,confirm_password,phone_number}),
        });
  
        const data = await backendResponse.json();
  
        if (data.jwt) {
          res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${data.jwt}; HttpOnly; Path=/;`);
          res.status(200).json({ success: true });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ success: false, error: 'Authentication failed' });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: 'Internal server error' });
      }
    } else {
      res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
      res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
    }
  }
```

and this is the way I fetch this api in my signup page:

```
"use client";




const Page: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<{ [key: string]: string }>({});

  async function handleSubmit(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
    const email = formData.get("email");
    const password = formData.get("password");
    const confirm_password = formData.get("confirm_password");
    const phone_number = formData.get("phone_number");

    const response = await fetch(
      "/api/signup",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email,
          password,
          confirm_password,
          phone_number,
        }),
      },
    );

    if (response.ok) {
      router.push("/profile");
    } else {
      const data = await response.json();
      setErrors(data.error);
    }
  }

 ...
};

export default Page;
```

This is the middleware for protected pages:

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'
 
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const token=request.cookies.get('token')?.value;

  //send request to api to validate the token
  const validateResponse=await fetch('api/accounts/signin/verify/',{
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  })

    // If the token is not valid (expired, not set, etc.), redirect to the login page
    if (!validateResponse.ok) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', request.url));
      }
     // If the token is valid and the path is not '/profile', redirect to the profile page
  if (token && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/profile')) {
    return Response.redirect(new URL('/profile', request.url));
  }
    // If there's no token and the path is not '/auth', redirect to the login page
    if (!token && !request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/auth')) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/auth/login', request.url));
      }
 

}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)'],
}
```